# Firestore Conundrum! Using .where() for arrays and strings

Tags: javascript, arrays, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am attempting to use the .where() functionality of firestore to detect if a certain string is in an array in the database. I have tried manipulating the first parameter of the function by adding brackets and other things to signify parts of an array to no avail.

```
//in this section I am getting the "yourLikes" integer (unrelated to the problem)
var liks = [];
var tempLiks = []
db.collection("users").where("uid", "==", uid)
.get()
.then(function(querySnapshot) {
    querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
      tempLiks = doc.data().yourLikes;
      // I am using a setTimeout() function to allow firebase to 
      // process the previous query and give me the doc.data().yourLikes for tempLiks
      setTimeout(function(){
      //Right here, the "usersLiked" data is an array, with a bunch of different values. 
      // I am trying to see if one of those values is doc.data().uid from my previous query. (I think) this is the problem.
       db.collection("memeInfo").where("usersLiked", "==", doc.data().uid)
        .get()
        .then(function(querySnapshot) {
            querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
              for (var i = 0; i < tempLiks.length; i++) {
                liks.push([tempLiks[i],doc.data().likes])
                console.log(liks)
              }
            })
          })
      },500)
```

If anyone has a solution to querying to see if individual values are in arrays without using a for loop forever (I will have possibly thousands of values in the usersLiked array), that would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the `array_contains` operator to filter based on array values, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#array_membership.

Therefore you have to adapt your code as follows:

```
//....
db.collection("memeInfo").where("usersLiked", "array-contains", doc.data().uid)
        .get()
        .then(function(querySnapshot) {...})
```

---

**Extra remark:** using `setTimeout()` for managing the asynchronous aspect of the queries to Firestore is not a correct approach (there is no assurance that the query will be done in less than 500 ms). You should manage the asynchronicity through the promises returned by the `get()` method. In particular, since you are firing several queries in parallel (through your loops), you need to use [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all).

---

**UPDATE** following your comment. You could use `Promise.all()` as follows:

```
var liks = [];
var tempLiks = [];
db.collection('users')
  .where('uid', '==', uid)
  .get()
  .then(function(querySnapshot) {
    // Here the Promise returned by the get() method is fulfilled, so you do have the results of the query and you do'nt need to use setTimeout

    var queries = [];
    querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
      tempLiks = doc.data().yourLikes;

      //We push each query to the queries array

      queries.push(
        db
          .collection('memeInfo')
          .where('usersLiked', '==', doc.data().uid)
          .get()
      );
    });

    //Then we call Promise.all()

    return Promise.all(queries);
  })
  .then(function(results) {
    //As explained in the doc "The returned promise is fulfilled with an array containing all the values of the iterable passed as argument (the queries array)."
    //So result is an array of QuerySnapshots, since the get() method returns a QuerySnapshot
    //Do whatever you want with the array
    console.log(results);
    results.forEach(function (querySnapshot) {
        querySnapshot.forEach(function (doc) {
            //.....
        });
    });
  });
```

Comment: How would you use promise.all() in this function? Can I just add it after .then()?